# Setting boolean variable does work in Remix but doesn't work is Mist

Tags: solidity, remix, rinkeby

When I run the following code in Remix IDE it works well, but when I deploy the contract in Mist on the Main network or on Rinkeby it sets the string variable, but not the bool. **users[msg.sender].isVerified** stays false while **users[msg.sender].fullName** is "John Smith"

```
 struct User {
        string fullName; 
        bool isVerified; 
 }

mapping(address => User) public users;

function f() {
users[msg.sender].fullName = "John Smith";
users[msg.sender].isVerified = true;
}
```